# Error wordpress "Call to undefined function aq_resize()"

Tags: errors

Since the update of wordpress 5.2, I get an error message when I play edit an article with a photo gallery.
An error was made in line 162 of my shortcodes.php file:
/home/sc1evyl7/public_html/vacances-appartements-mediterranee.com/wp-content/themes/theplace/inc/shortcodes.php. 
Error message : Call to undefined function aq_resize()

Is the syntax of this line no longer valid?
size()

Ligne 162
$im['thumb'] = aq_resize( $im['full-size'], 90, 90, true );

Thank you for help

Comment: `aq_resize()` seems to be provided by *Aqua Resizer* (https://github.com/sy4mil/Aqua-Resizer). Is your theme supporting Aqua Resizer or may a plugin of yours is doing so? If you've switched themes or disabled some plugins, maybe that's the root of the issue.

Comment: Thank you Eduardo, my theme comes with aqua resizer and work perfectly during 3 years. But there is a problem with wordpress 5.2, only with photos galllery specific in the theme. It is good with wordpress Gallery...